# simple_fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I have a simple_field and I pass an object to a partial file. I do this in the partial :

```
<%= f.input :address,
            :as => :hidden,
            :label => "Address :",
            :input_html=>{
              :required => false,
              :class => "address"
            } %>
```

I want to use `:as => hidden` depending on a certain condition. I mean the field should be hidden if a condition is true. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your options hash separately and then add the hidden parameter if necessary

```
options = {
        :label => "Address :",
        :input_html=>{
          :required => false,
          :class => "address"
        } 
      }
if condition_is_true? then options[:as] = "hidden" end
<%= f.input :address, options %>
```